# Net::SSH forward not working

Tags: ruby, ssh, net-ssh

I want to forward a port via Net::SSH like this:

```
ssh = Net::SSH.start('host', 'user', config: true)
ssh.forward.local(3333, 'localhost', 80)
ssh.loop
```

which to my understanding translates to the equivalent of:

```
ssh user@host -L 3333:localhost:80
```

With the command line version I can send an HTTP request to `localhost:3333` and get an answer from `localhost:80` on the remote host. With the Ruby version I don't get any answer.

Any ideas why?

**Edit:**

I tried `net-ssh-gateway` and it works. Looking at its code, I can't really see what's different there in terms of what it does to establish the connection.